# Do blood dragons have a "weak spot"

Tags: far-cry-3-blood-dragon

During my playthrough of Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon, I've noticed a small glowing spot on the blood dragons' chests. Is this some sort of weak point? Is there a way to deal extra damage to one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the glowing spot on their chest does considerably more damage to them when you hit it.

Comment: By the way: A dialog during a story mission tells you about this, but this happens quite late in the game.